# Express route, database access and NodeJS: What's the best way?

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, node-mysql

I'm currently developping an application using NodeJs, Express, WebSocket and node-mysql. Currently, here is the global idea:

The server has a login route and looks like this:

```
var configuration = require("./configuration");
var db = require("./database");
var Response = require("./models/response");

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require("http").Server(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var socketJwt = require('socketio-jwt');

app.use(function(req, res, next)
{
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8080");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

    next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.post('/login', function(req, res)
{
    db.player
        .login(req.body.username, req.body.password)
        .then(function(result)
        {
            var profile = {
                id: result.d[0].id_player,
                name: req.body.username,
                email: 's.sougnez@areaprog.com'
            };

            jwt.sign(profile, configuration.jwtSecret, { expireInMinutes: 60 * 5 }, function(token)
            {
                res.json(new Response({ token: token }));
            });
        },
        function(err)
        {
            res.status(err.getStatus()).json(err);
        });
});

io
    .on('connection', socketJwt.authorize({
        secret: configuration.jwtSecret,
        timeout: 2000
    }))
    .on('authenticated', function(socket)
    {
    });

server.listen(8081);
```

The "db" module is used to connect and query a mysql database. Here is the main idea of this file:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var configuration = require("../configuration");

var Promise = require("promise");
var Response = require("../models/response");

var con = null;

function connect(handleConnection, connection)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        if (handleConnection !== false)
        {
            con = mysql.createConnection(configuration.db);

            con.connect(function(err)
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    reject(err);

                    return;
                }

                con.beginTransaction(function(err)
                {
                    if (err)
                    {
                        reject(err);

                        return;
                    }

                    resolve();
                });
            })
        }
        else
        {
            con = connection;

            resolve();
        }
    });
}

function commit(handleConnection)
{
    ...
}

function executeNonQuery()
{
    ...
}

function executeQuery(query, args)
{
    ...
}

function hasRow()
{
    ...
}

function lastId()
{
    ...
}

function rollback(handleConnection)
{
    ...
}

module.exports.commit = commit;
module.exports.connect = connect;
module.exports.executeNonQuery = executeNonQuery;
module.exports.executeQuery = executeQuery;
module.exports.hasRow = hasRow;
module.exports.lastId = lastId;
module.exports.rollback = rollback;

module.exports.player = require("./player").init(this);
```

And finally, we have the "player" module:

```
var Promise = require('promise');

var player = (function()
{
    var db = null;

    var init = function(database)
    {
        db = database;

        return this;
    };

    var login = function(name, pass, handleConnection, connection)
    {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
        {
            var data = null;

            db
                .connect(handleConnection, connection)
                .then(function()
                {
                    var query = 'SELECT `id_player`, `language`, `password`, `salt`, `failed_attempt`, `last_ip`, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`blocked_until`) AS `blocked_until` \
                         FROM `players` \
                         WHERE `name` = ?';

                    var params = [ name ];

                    return db.executeQuery(query, params);
                })
                .then(function(result)
                {
                    if (result.d.length === 0)
                    {
                        result.setError('Invalid username');

                        throw result;
                    }

                    data = result;

                    return db.commit();
                })
                .then(function()
                {
                    resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(function(err)
                {
                    db
                        .rollback(handleConnection)
                        .then(function()
                        {
                            reject(err);
                        });
                });
        });
    };

    return {
        init: init,
        login: login
    }
}());

module.exports = player;
```

Okay, so actually, everything works as expected. I open the page, click on "login", then it calls the route "/login" of the code above, grant the access and create a websocket connection. This whole code is the beginning and is subject to change, but yesterday, while reading a post on NodeJs, I realized that the db module was a singleton, so I'm wondering...

Is it a valid architecture ? What if two users connect at the same time, don't I have a risk that the "connect" function of "db" called by the second user overrides the variable "con" initialized by the call made by the first user ? I tried to put a long for loop yesterday in the login process and I noticed that the second user call was waiting for the first one to finish => normally, I won't have conflict issue but, in this case, does that mean that the performance of my server will be quite crappy if there are a lot of users on the site ?

Moreover, as I said, I will use WebSockets, and this ones will use the db module as well, so if I have a lot of user, the server will often blocks users while it's processing query of previous users, no ?

Finally, I'm really hesitating for the db module. Is it correct to leave it as a singleton or should I create a type for it and create a new object of this type for every database request ?

These questions are quite "specific" and I don't really know what to look on Google to find an answer, so here I am :-)

Thanks a lot for your answers

Comment: As an advise, to maximize the possibility to get a useful answer, You really should try to make smaller questions, extracting their "essence" and leaving out the noise...

Comment: I tried but I didn't see a clear way to explain the architecture of my project without showing the main piece of it.

Comment: You can setup your mysql to use pool of connections which is probably better. The for loop is blocking operation but call to DB is not it's asynchronous which means node will process another request while waiting for response from db.

Comment: Interesting... And what about the singleton vs type question ? If a query is being executed and another users tries to log in, in the case of a singleton, the line "con = mysql.createConnection(configuration.db);" would override the value of "con", no ?